# Lost access to the unity interface how to fix? 

Tags: 11.10, unity

o.k, this is embarrassing:

I have installed Compiz Config Settings Manager and tried to fix it so that the transition time between changing tabs (using alt+tab) will be short.  by accident I un-pressed V from something else, and it asked me about a conflict - I pressed the "x" button to close the window and as a result I stopped seeing the unity interface.  That is - I can not see any buttons of the left side.

I went to the terminal (ctrl+alt+F1) and ran

```
ccsm
```

As a result I got the following error:

```
$ ccsm
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
  warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ccsm", line 93, in <module>
    import ccm
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ccm/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ccm.Conflicts import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ccm/Conflicts.py", line 26, in <module>
    from ccm.Constants import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ccm/Constants.py", line 29, in <module>
    CurrentScreenNum = gtk.gdk.display_get_default().get_default_screen().get_number()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_default_screen'
```

What should I do next?

Comment: have you tried unity --replace and if fails unity --reset?

Comment: When running the unity --replace I get:  warning: no display variable set, setting it to :0  unity-panel-service: no process found

Comment: and now it doesn't respond to any more commands.  Can I return to putting commands without restarting?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu do you use? I cannot see it in a tag!

Comment: there we go ctrl+c  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1047348

Answer (score 6):

This seemed fixed once I went to terminal (ctrl+alt+F1) and pressed:

```
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compizconfig-1
rm ~/.compiz-1/session/*
rm ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/config
unity --reset
```

source:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1866462

Comment: Glad that finally you can enjoy your computer!

Answer (score 4):

You can try to reset unity settings with unity --replace and if fails try unity --reset
If all those fails and you still cannot get to CCSM then reinstall it with commands:
if you don't want to remove setting substitute purge with remove in command below

```
sudo apt-get purge compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

**Disclaimer**: Iam not sure the link Iam about to post is still applicable as thread dates to 2008.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=799070

**UPDATE**
It seems as if you are not yet logged in GUI, and so there is no XServer running yet. Try in failsafe mode (recovery mode) and fix things from there

Comment: ok, I ran both commands (without errors).  But the problem stays the same.

Comment: Hi Stefano - how do I get there? and once there - how do I fix? :)

Comment: Hi again - I see that my computer freezes when I try to enter to recovery mode.  But in any event, it is not clear to me what should be hapanning when I am there vs the simple ctrl+alt+T

Comment: can you reach tty terminal, I mean that black screen where you can login and type commands?

Comment: Hi Stefano - I can reach it without a problem (through ctrl+alt+F1).  The problem is that even after running the above code - I am still left with the same issue :(

Comment: can you test if sudo startx have any effect. If you do this you will later need to remove the Xauthority file it generates!

Comment: tried and got:  faterl server error: server is alreadt active for display 0

Comment: if this server is no longer running. remove /tmp/.x0-lock and start again

Comment: cool then try sudo rm /tmp/.x0-lock and re-run sudo startx
Just another question, do you reach login manager (gdm or lightdm)

Comment: o.k, I seem to have fixed it - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The reason was compiz which I removed. Here is my solution:

1. Make sure that **Intel Graphics driver and Nvidia Graphics driver do not conflict** in which case you can use:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
   ```

   ...to remove the Nvidia graphics driver.
2. Make sure you do not remove **unity-desktop**、**compiz**、**ccsm**
   which you can reinstall by running:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge unity-desktop compiz ccsm  
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   sudo reboot
   ```

   after restart your computer

   ```
   sudo apt-get install unity-desktop compiz ccsm
   ```
3. Clear the **old error gnome configure files**.

   ```
   cd ~  
   ls -all  
   sudo rm -rf .gnome2/ .gnome2_private/ .config/ .gconfd/ .gconf/ .gnome/
   ```
4. Restart your computer.

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```